# Cannot connect Spring Boot application to Docker Mysql container - unknown database

Tags: docker, spring-boot

In docker a created network

```
docker network create mysql-network
```

Then I create mysql image

```
docker container run -d -p 3306:3306 --net=mysql-network --name mysql-hibernate -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -v hibernate:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

When I run **docker ps** everything seems OK
[image]

This is my **application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
useSSL=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

I also tried

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-hibernate:3306/test
```

But I will always get an error on startup

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test'

How's that possible that it doesn't know database 'test' ? I specified name in docker like this
 **-e MYSQL_DATABASE=test**
What am I missing ?

Comment: that comes because you didn't create the database 'test'  try to create it with command line or use MySQL workbench

Comment: well I though the whole point of running docker container in my PC is that I don't have to install mysql / workbench into my computer and configure it :/. I though I can pull an image and use it anyway thanks for pointing me right direction

Comment: you can also use docker-compose to use tow images as a DB server and an Admin UI (PHPMYADMIN, Adminer ..) search the Hub you can find some images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it is bit late but I'll answer anyway so people coming here can benefit ;) 
Your configuration overall seems alright. When you get error like this you can add flag param set to true in your application.properties in line where you set datasource url.
So you will come up with something like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Hope this helps!